# How to use more then $group in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
[

{
    "_id":"56569bff5fa4f203c503c792",
    "Status":{
        "StatusID":2,
        "StatusObjID":"56559aad5fa4f21ca8492277",
        "StatusValue":"Closed"
    },
    "OwnerPractice":{
        "PracticeObjID":"56559aad5fa4f21ca8492291",
        "PracticeValue":"CCC",
        "PracticeID":3
    },
    "Name":"AA"
},
{
    "_id":"56569bff5fa4f203c503c792",
    "Status":{
        "StatusID":2,
        "StatusObjID":"56559aad5fa4f21ca8492277",
        "StatusValue":"Open"
    },
    "OwnerPractice":{
        "PracticeObjID":"56559aad5fa4f21ca8492292",
        "PracticeValue":"K12",
        "PracticeID":2
    },
    "Name":"BB"
}
```

]

In above json response,

How to group by PracticeValue,StatusValue into single function,

the below code to be used to group only StatusValue,please help how to group Practice value with the same function,

```
Opp.aggregate([
     {$group: {
         _id: '$Status.StatusValue',
         count: {$sum: 1}
     }}
], function (err, result) {
    res.send(result);
});
```

and my response is,

```
[
    {
        "_id":"Deleted",
        "count":0
    },
    {
        "_id":"Open",
        "count":1
    },
    {
        "_id":"Closed",
        "count":1
    }
]


please help me, how to use more then $group function..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by multiple fields like this:

```
var resultAggr = {Status: [], Practice: []};

Opp.aggregate(
  [
     {$group: { _id: '$Status.StatusValue', count: {$sum: 1} }}
  ], function (err, statusResult) {
      resultAggr.Status = statusResult;
      Opp.aggregate(
      [
         {$group: { _id: '$OwnerPractice.PracticeValue', count: {$sum: 1} }}
      ], function (err, practiceResult) {
          resultAggr.Practice = practiceResult;
          res.send([resultAggr])
      });
});
```

Comment: the above code not getting expected response,the count value not correct

Comment: I am Expecting the below response format,[{ "Status":
   [{
        "_id":"Deleted",
        "count":0
    },
    {
        "_id":"Open",
        "count":1
    },
    {
        "_id":"Closed",
        "count":1
    }]},
{"Practice":[
 {
        "_id":"K12",
        "count":31
    },
 {
        "_id":"HK",
        "count":12
    }
]}]

Comment: In that case you need to perform two aggregate queries